# Unable to thrown an error in Express Node

Tags: node.js, express

I have a following Post route

```
router.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const newMessage = new Message({
    From: req.body.sendersPhoneNumber,
    To: 9188123560,
    OTP: req.body.randomNumber,
    Message: req.body.TextToSend
  })

  newMessage.save().then((response) => {
    const from = "NEXMO"
    const to = response.To
    const text = response.Message
    nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, {type: 'unicode'}, (error, responseData) => {
      if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw  new Error (error)
      } else {
        console.dir(responseData)
        res.send(responseData)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

In this, I want to throw an error If there is an error for which i did something like this

```
 if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw  new Error (error)
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to be working, can some help me by sharing, how can we throw an error in nodeJs

This is my request from frontend

```
axios.post(test_url_base +  "/contact/message", this.state).then(response => {
```

Comment: in your throw statement, there is two spaces after throw keyword that may gives you error or may not execute statement properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 01:**

Line 1: Need a third parameter, `next` to pass the error to the next handler.

Line 16: pass the error to the next error handler, `return next(error);`

NB: In your root file like `index.js` or `server.js` or whatever you are using, You need an error handler, like,

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
   console.log('Found a error');
});
```

Your final code will be,

```
router.post("/message", async (req, res, next) => {
  const newMessage = new Message({
    From: req.body.sendersPhoneNumber,
    To: 9188123560,
    OTP: req.body.randomNumber,
    Message: req.body.TextToSend
  })

  newMessage.save().then((response) => {
    const from = "NEXMO"
    const to = response.To
    const text = response.Message
    nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, {type: 'unicode'}, (error, responseData) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return next(error);
      } else {
        console.dir(responseData)
        res.send(responseData)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

**Solution 2:**

If you encounter an error, pass the error to the client side,
Use `res.status(400).send(error);`

In this case, your code should be,

```
router.post("/message", async (req, res, next) => {
  const newMessage = new Message({
    From: req.body.sendersPhoneNumber,
    To: 9188123560,
    OTP: req.body.randomNumber,
    Message: req.body.TextToSend
  })

  newMessage.save().then((response) => {
    const from = "NEXMO"
    const to = response.To
    const text = response.Message
    nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, {type: 'unicode'}, (error, responseData) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.send(error);
      } else {
        console.dir(responseData)
        res.send(responseData)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have done that is also correct way but i don't get why it is not working.

you can also try this one

```
if (error) {
   return next(error)
}
```

or you can also do this

```
res.render('error', { error: err })
```

Answer (score 0):

Put try catch block , so that any error thrown from try block gets caught in catch block.

```
router.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const newMessage = new Message({
        From: req.body.sendersPhoneNumber,
        To: 9188123560,
        OTP: req.body.randomNumber,
        Message: req.body.TextToSend
    })

    newMessage.save().then((response) => {
        const from = "NEXMO"
        const to = response.To
        const text = response.Message
        nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, { type: 'unicode' }, (error, responseData) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                throw new Error(error)
            } else {
                console.dir(responseData)
                res.send(responseData)
            }
        })
    });
}
catch (e) {
    res.send({ status: 400, error: e });
}
})
```